# How to send crt file in api request using npm request-promise

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, key, crt

I am new to the certificate file concept.
I have been given a CRT file along with passphrase to send in an API.
As I am using request-promise package from npm. To add certificates we can do this.

(Note: I have been given only one file that is abc.crt).

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://api.some-server.com/',
    agentOptions: {
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
        // Or use `pfx` property replacing `cert` and `key` when using private key, certificate and CA certs in PFX or PKCS12 format:
        // pfx: fs.readFileSync(pfxFilePath),
        passphrase: 'password',
        securityOptions: 'SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3'
    }
};
```

By doing this i am getting this error

```
Error: RequestError: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

I have a few questions related to this.

1) What is use of CRT files?
2) How will I get the .key file from the CRT file?